# How can I translate the phrase "Does it make sense?"

Tags: phrases

Very often when a person describes his point he asks the audience a question.

> Does it make sense?

Is it correct to rephrase it as "Is it understandable?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than *does* ***it*** *make sense* or *is* ***it*** *understandable*, I'd use *that* (where *that* refers to what you've just explained.) Using *it* here is common among native speakers, but not idiomatic.

Otherwise the two do mean the same thing in this context, yes! "Does that make sense?" or "Does everybody get that?" would be common things to say in this context, and they do essentially mean "Was what I just said understandable?"

Comment: So, may I interpret the phrase "Does it make sense"  like "Do you get it"?

Comment: @Warlock: Yes. That is exactly what "does that make sense?" means.

Answer (score 1):

These aren't *exactly* synonymous, although they are close. "Does it make sense?" seems more restrictive.

Something nonsensical can be understandable. For example, consider the question:

> "I can hear the toothpaste singing, can you?"

Is that *understandable*? Yes, I can understand what you are asking.

Does that *make sense*? Not really – toothpaste doesn't sing.

"Make sense" and "sensible" here mean "tell a coherent story," or "be consistent and reasonable," or something similar.

Comment: It might be good to explain the meaning of the phrase "make sense" and "nonsensical"; the asker seems to be hung up on this in particular.